# XML to JSON conversion using XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have to covert an XML to JSON format using XPath expression. Is there any way by which I can achieve it?

I tried using the xml-to-json function but I am not getting how should I provide the arguments to the function.

I have to run the XPath expression only, I cannot use XSLT to achieve the same.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
        <location>DL</location>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="es">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
        <location>UP</location>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
        <location>  DL</location>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
        <location>dl </location>
    </book>
    <category>web</category>
</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really stretching the capability of XPath, even if you have version 3.1. You should really be using XSLT or XQuery.

However, I think it is possible - but not using the xml-to-json() function. You need something like

```
serialize (
  map { "bookstore": 
    array { //book !
      map { "category" : string(@category),
            "title" : string(title),
            "authors" : 
               array { author ! string(.) },
            "year" : number(year)
          }
    }
  },
  map{"method" : "json"}
)
```

Comment: Couple of things I just wanted to check with you. 1. Which IDE are you using to run the above XPath expression?  2. When I tried executing the above XPath expression in Exchange XML editor, it is throwing an error message mentioning : "Expected: )".

Comment: Fixed a trivial typo and it now runs in oXygen.

Comment: As far as I can see Exchange XML Editor was last released in 2005, so it's hardly going to support XPath 3.1, is it?

Comment: What does ! mark mean in the XPath expression? I mean what purpose does ! serve when we use it in : array{ author ! string(.) }  ?

Comment: It's a mapping operator: it evaluates the expression on the right once for each item in the sequence on the left. Similar to "/" but without the sort-and-deduplicate semantics. In this example "/" would serve the same purpose.

Comment: With map{"method" : "json"}, I believe the key is "method" and its value is "json" and with this you are specifying the format in which the output should come.Is this a predefined value? Just out of curiosity, what other formats can we specify in place of "json".

Comment: @DeepakJain Questions like this aren't an efficient way of getting information. You need to read the specs.

Comment: Just for the record, I got my answer by reading the documentation at: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-serialize